# how to get the call connected time using Telephony framework using ios5?

Tags: xcode, ios4, ios5, core-telephony

I want to capture the **timestamp** of incoming call and out going call. I read that, this could be possible using CoreTelephony Framework. I have tried the code given here [Capture incoming Callevent using coretelephony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519902/capture-incoming-callevent-using-coretelephony)  . I had placed code inside the **applicationwillresignActive** method. I have run the test by giving the call while my application in the foreground, but i am not getting any messages in the log. Event handler is code is not executing even when the call event happens. I am not getting where i am wrong?

**Thanks in advance**

Pushpa

Answer (score 0):

you can see this link [call details](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)

From this u will get date of call and duration of call. And with the help of Core telephony u can detect call's incoming state. When u get a incoming call then generate a time stamp.

I think it may be help you.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

This method no longer works in iOS5+.  Is there a new method? This app seems to have it working

https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/navita-t.e.m.-personal/id590228620?mt=8